# Baseline Grid question

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, text

So im new to using Baseline grids - little late i know.. but i have a question about this document i am making.

1st picture: In the pictures below is it common practice to align the quote on the left to the grid - or is it acceptable to have it not align to the grid 2nd picture (only have the text to the right align)?

if im aligning the quote it seems like its very spaced out. is there a way to use alternate baselines or is this just the way it is?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are no rules. `:)` It's all a matter of preference. Grids, all of them, are *always* merely *suggestions*. Paul Rand would have exploded if forced to use grids. Just do what looks good to you.

Comment: A third option is to set your quote’s leading to touch the baseline grid every fourth line (you’re almost there in your second option). That way, it’ll feel more in keeping with the main paragraphs, but will have a bit more breathing space.